# student-teacher model in keras

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm converting student-teacher model in below url to keras one.

https://github.com/chengshengchan/model_compression/blob/master/teacher-student.py

How can I give input to two model(student, teacher) and get one output from only student in keras?
I'll set teacher's all tensors with trainable=false, and loss function as difference between student and teacher's output like below :

```
tf_loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(teacher - student)/batch_size
```

As I know, it is possible to give input to only one model when defining model.fit. But in this cases, I should it to both of teacher and student model.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only implementation I have seen in Keras involves building 2 separate functions which either widen or deepen weight layers from the teacher model as initial weights for the student model. 
I am not sure if it is precisely that Hinton et al. (2015) distillation to be honest, but it is teacher-student.
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3491

Comment: Um,. It is little bit different. Above link is a kind of transfer learning. To improve swallow model, they copy weight from more deep model called teacher. What I want to do is making swallow model learn through difference it's output and deep model's output.

Comment: And I know firstly suggester of teacher-student model is from Rich Caruana 2014. http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5484-do-deep-nets-really-need-to-be-deep.pdf Hinton had used just some trick, temperature on the difference. Anyway, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @semenbari ye I'm implementing same thing as you in my dissertation shortly. as in the proper non-transfer kind. let me know if youre able to do it in Keras. sorry not to be of help.

Comment: Hi, I added another answer to my question. Reference it. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 10):

Below is very simple student-teacher model in keras.
I hope it might be helpful to someone like me.
Good job!

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation

nb_classes = 10

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, 784)
X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, 784)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)



from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Merge
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, RMSprop

batch_size = 128
nb_classes = 10
nb_epoch = 3

teacher = Sequential()
teacher.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(784,)))
teacher.add(Dense(10))
teacher.add(Activation('softmax'))

teacher.summary()
teacher.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=RMSprop(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = teacher.fit(X_train, Y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
                    verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
score = teacher.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

for i in range(len(teacher.layers)):
    setattr(teacher.layers[i], 'trainable', False)



Y_train = np.zeros((60000, 10))



student = Sequential()
student.add(Dense(10, input_dim=784))
student.add(Activation('softmax'))
student.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

from keras.layers import *
def negativeActivation(x):
    return -x

negativeRight = Activation(negativeActivation)(student.output) 
diff = Add()([teacher.output,negativeRight])


model = Model(inputs=[teacher.input, student.input], outputs=[diff])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['acc'])

model.summary(line_length=150)
model.fit([X_train, X_train], [Y_train], batch_size=128, nb_epoch=5)


print student.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
```