# How to use custom loss fuction in keras?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I want to use custom loss function, not like by calculating from difference between y_true, y_pred.
For examples, I mean another gap something like y_pred and another model's result y_pred2.
I have found a week, but I couldn't find similar one.
Is it possible this in keras?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use a custom loss, but your question is quite unclear about the custom loss you need to use.

Comment: Yes, this question is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368241/student-teacher-model-in-keras . There are deep model and swallow model which want to resemble the deep model. So after comparing each model's result and by decreasing difference them, learning is done. In above, y_pred is swallow model's and y_pred2 is from deep model's. So I don't need y_true. Then keras should support this type loss function.

Comment: In this case y_true is just the labels that are generated by the deep model, you can just precompute those and pass it to Keras, no need to involve the loss function in it.

Comment: Yes, I know. I mean in case of it need to calculate dynamically the result and not just comparing the final y value, but comparing intermediate output such as previous value of softmax.

Comment: it's maybe not the good point of view. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368241/student-teacher-model-in-keras/43700164#43700164 provides another approach.